# How to fix react router 404 error on production

Tags: reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404, auth0

Router works on my local, but i can not pass the login screen in production. I got an `404 - File or directory not found.`

net/callback?code=c_FJL3txY1QZk6l_&state=lLBGkLyhwluUMs08r4nmRxAH22nYQj3L

Authentication works, i get the error after i logged in, i can see on Auth0 that i logged in the system but when i type(after 404, instead of above url) `http://my-site.net/#/board` it redirects to `http://my-site.net/#/login`.

`"homepage": "http://my-site.net/"`

```
export const AUTH_CONFIG = {
  domain: 'dev-o00fke8o.eu.auth0.com',
  clientId: 'dwbY5EkuW2pK16CzIf4AaUCQkEsTKQHQ',
  callbackUrl: 'http://my-site.net/callback'
}
```

my routes.js

```
<Router history={history}>
      <HashRouter>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={props => <Login auth={auth} {...props} />}
        />

        <Route
          path="/brand"
          render={props =>
            !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
              <Redirect to="/login" />
            ) : (
              <Brand auth={auth} {...props} />
            )
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/board"
          render={props =>
            !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
              <Redirect to="/login" />
            ) : (
              <Board auth={auth} {...props} />
            )
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/Profile"
          render={props =>
            !auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
              <Redirect to="/login" />
            ) : (
              <Profile auth={auth} {...props} />
            )
          }
        />

        <Route
          path="/login"
          render={props => <Login auth={auth} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/callback"
          render={props => {
            handleAuthentication(props);
            return <Callback {...props} />;
          }}
        />
      </HashRouter>
      </Router>
```

part where i want to redirect to next phase if authenticated

```
  handleAuthentication() {
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult);
        history.replace('/board');
      } else if (err) {
        history.replace('/board');
        console.log(err);
        alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further details.`);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that when you are hitting: http://my-site.net/callback?code=c_FJL3txY1QZk6l_&state=lLBGkLyhwluUMs08r4nmRxAH22nYQj3L, it's actually your server router that comes in play, not react-router, you are missing the #, it should be .net/#/callback

Comment: Thx for the answer. I tried it and now new url is `my-site.net/#/access_token=zWpyuQ... ` and i have white blank page

Comment: What is the route supposed to be? What you pasted is not a valid URL, access_token needs to be a query param, you need to add a ? before it: /#/access_token=zWpyuQ -> /#/?access_token=zWpyuQ